# 403 forbidden error when accessing API with X-API-KEY authentication

Tags: python, postman, http-status-code-403, api-key

I stumbled upon an error when trying to access “EDQM Standard Terms” dictionary via API — this is a dictionary of various pharmaceutical formulations used in the EU, and I wanted to use a Python script to fetch the data for further processing.
The API documentation published by EDQM is really scarce:
[Standard Terms API documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QHZS.png)

I tried accessing one of the endpoints listed in API documentation — namely, a list of languages — and no matter what I try, I get **403 FORBIDDEN** error as a reply. I checked this directly from Python, as well as with Postman, and the result is the same. I double-checked and I am using the correct API key, and the Web Service is active for my EDQM account.

I wrote the following functions:

1. assemble_string

```
def assemble_sig(verb: str, uri: str, timestamp: str):
    string_to_sign = verb + "&" + uri + "&" + HOST + "&" + timestamp
    return string_to_sign
```

This function generates the signature mentioned in API docs based on the URI, ‘GET’ verb and current time/date.

2. sign_string

```
def sign_string(key: str, msg: str):
    signature = hmac.new(
        key.encode(),
        msg.encode(),
        digestmod=hashlib.sha512,
    ).hexdigest()
    signature_b64 = base64.b64encode(signature.encode())
    signature_final = signature_b64.decode()
    return signature_final[-22:]
```

This function takes my API key and the assembled string, encodes it and returns the 22 last characters.

3. api_header

```
def api_header(uri: str):
    d = dt.datetime.now()
    edqm_timestamp = format_date_time(d.timestamp())
    
    api_signature = assemble_sig(HTTP_VERB, uri, edqm_timestamp)
    signed_string = sign_string(API_KEY, api_signature)

    api_hdr = {
        "Date": edqm_timestamp,
        "X-STAPI-KEY": f"{LOGIN}|{signed_string}",
    }
    return api_hdr
```

This function, using the previous two ones, assembles the header for the API request.
Generated header looks like this:

```
{'Date': 'Sun, 06 Feb 2022 16:43:06 GMT', 'X-STAPI-KEY': 'mylogin|FhYzRiMTllNjhlNzQ0MWI='}
```

where **mylogin** is replaced with my real login.

The entire code for the API request:

```
edqm_req_url = f"{HOST}{URI['languages']}"
edqm_req_header = api_header(URI["languages"])

edqm_session = requests.Session()
edqm_req = edqm_session.get(
    edqm_req_url,
    headers=edqm_req_header,
)
print(edqm_req.raise_for_status())
```

I already tried the following:

- different encoding in *sign_string* function — when *encode()* or *decode()* are used with UTF-8 or ASCII encoding parameter, I get **400 BAD REQUEST**;
- using Authorization header *{"Authorization": "X-STAPI-KEY = mylogin|signed_string”}*, but I also got **400 BAD REQUEST**.

I will really appreciate any help with getting this thing working!

Thanks :-)

Kuba

Comment: Hi jkosciel, what I try to do in cases where I don't trust the documentation or I simply don't know what I'm doing wrong, is capturing the network traffic of an app or website that already implemented endpoints of the API I'm trying to call and compare that with the request I'm trying to do. I'm not sure if this is really helpful to you, since an important requirement is that you know of such apps/sites...

Comment: Hi PixelPixel, thanks for your comment! :-) I already tried analysing some traffic on EDQM website with browsershark, but this has not helped. This is a very niche database, and it is not used by many other websites/apps. I also approached EDQM’s helpdesk, and they came with a solution that does not work either...

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully accessed the edqm api with authentication. Let's describe the variable of the signature.

```
- StringToSign = HTTP-Verb + "&" + URI + "&" + HOST + "&" + Date
  - HTTP-Verb
    - http request method
    - usually like GET、POST
  - URI
    - http request uri
    - exclude scheme、host from url
    - for example if the url is **https://standardterms.edqm.eu:443/standardterms/api/v1/domains**, the true uri is **/standardterms/api/v1/domains**
  - HOST
    - http request host
    - constant, should be **standardterms.edqm.eu**
  - Date
    - same with the Date header as above
  - &
    - just a string value not operator
- 22 last characters of Base64( HMAC-SHA512( YourSecretAccessKey, StringToSign ) )
  - you need to sign **StringToSign** with **YourSecretAccessKey** using HMAC-SHA512
  - then encoded with Base64
  - finally keep the last 22 characters of the base64 result
```

You could access my github https://github.com/asd1245dss/edqm-sync/edit/main/README.md to learn more

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I also managed to get the API working, although I had to contact their IT support. Below I am posting the working solution:

> String to sign should be as specified in the help page, as shown
> below: StringToSign = HTTP-Verb (=GET) + "&" + URI
> (=/standardterms/api/v1/languages) + "&" + HOST
> (=standardterms.edqm.eu) + "&" + Date; For this request, try to use:
> 'GET&/standardterms/api/v1/languages&standardterms.edqm.eu&Mon, 07 Feb
> 2022 12:35:02 GMT'
>
> If using this, you still do not get the expected result, you could
> check your signature generation script. Here are the testing
> parameter:
>
> String to sign:
> "GET&/standardterms/api/v1/languages&standardterms.edqm.eu&Mon, 07 Feb
> 2022 14:20:00 GMT" Secret key: "mysecret" Generated signature:
> "Z3DZ5tAtcmHGjeA4MUQw=="

It should also be noted that the HOST parameter should *not* include 'http://' or 'https://'.

Cheers,
Kuba